# Malsup cycle2 slides based on width?

Tags: jquery, jquery-cycle2

I'm trying to show 3 slides for an ipad layout, and 1 slide when the user is on their iphone.  Is this possible with cycle2?  How would I do this?

Comment: you could set config options  based on window width before initializing plugin

Comment: So on iPhone you would like to show only the first slide of the cycle? Or would you like to create a carousel type of slider http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/demo/carousel.php showing three slides next to each other in iPad and only one on iPhone?